# How to program a GXT Menu object so that its submenus expand to the left by default instead of right?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have a GWT application where the GXT Menu/MenuItem widgets are used. The menu is on the top left corner of the work area and then there are multiple levels of submenus to it:

```
==========================================
                            [-Main Menu-] ||
                            | Option1   | ||
             -------------  | Option2 > | || 
            | Option2.1  |  |    :      | || //no space to expand submenu 2; expands on left
            | Option2.2 >|----------    | ||
            |     :    |Option2.2.1|    | || //Space available for submenu 2.2; expands on right, 
            |-----:----|Option2.2.2|----| || //therefor overlaps with Main menu options
                       |     :     |      ||
                       |-----:-----|      ||
```

- by default, the first level submenu opens to the bottom
- The second level submenu opens to the left (because there is no space on the right)
- the third level submenu opens to the right thus overlapping the main menu.

Is there a way to control the behavior so that submenus at all levels keep opening to the left instead of trying to open on the right while there is space there (and opening on the left only if and only if no space is available to the right)?
Simply put, I want the opposite of what is currently happening: If there is space on left, expand on left; else expand on right.

I looked at the GXT classes MenuAppearance, MenuItemAppearance and the method Menu.setSubmenuAlignment() but nothing seems to provide what I want to do. It seems to me this would have been a common requirement which is why I am trying to look at an API solution. I do not want to extend and write the functionality myself unless that is th only way.

Comment: Please post some sample code to resolve the issue quickly.

Comment: This is a very generic question, nothing specific to my applicaton. I am not sure how a sample code will help. Instead I have reworded my problem to a better structure

Comment: I asked for code because I have to code to create the same design as your have described. Rather than solving the problem I have to code it first.